# "Lest" or "Or?"

Tags: etymology, word-usage, formality

Colloquially, I would always use *or* where I would formally use *lest*. For example, "go to sleep, or you'll be tired" versus "go to sleep, lest you be tired."

Has this usage of *or* been around for a while, or have people phrased sentences like this differently? Perhaps "If you don't go to sleep, you'll be tired."? Is it acceptable to use *or* this way in formal English?

Comment: Personally, I would use "or" in either circumstance, if offering an alternative.

But I would use "lest" if I wanted to stress a less present consequence.

Comment: In the US, at least, "lest" is considered "quaint" and perhaps a bit ostentatious.

Comment: Apart from 'lest' sounding archaic, "Go to sleep lest you be tired" means "Go to sleep or you **might well** be tired [later]".

Comment: What @EdwinAshworth said. *Do A **lest** B happens* (or *...lest B **happen***; I've no particular preference) raises the *possibility* that B might happen if you don't do A, but that's not the same as *Do A **or** B will happen / happens* (where Simple Present is a bit "poetic, literary"). The ***or*** version unambiguously asserts that failure to do A will *definitely* lead to B happening (it's not just a *possibility*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Lest' is an old word - OED citations begin around 1000AD.  It is a more concise way of saying "to avoid the possibility that".  As such it is still a perfectly good word introducing a clause expressive of something to be prevented or guarded against, although this fineness of expression is not commonly communicated in this way today.

Ordinary speech today often uses a less nuanced vocabulary and communicates the additional meaning using prosody.

***"Go to sleep, lest you be tired"*** - is a suggestion that you should try to sleep because otherwise it is likely you will be tired.

***"Go to sleep, or you'll be tired"*** - is an unambiguous assertion.  Unless you go to sleep you *will* be tired.

And, of course, symbols and places of remembrance often explain their purpose, explicitly, by saying 'Lest we forget'.

Answer (score 1):

I think of 'lest' as a form of unless.  In your example, "lest"would mean "unless you want to be tired'.  'Or'in this case means the words after it describe a definite consequence of not going to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize until I found it clued this way in crosswords, what sets **lest** apart from similar words.  From Merriam-Webster.com:

Full Definition of lest
:  for fear that —often used after an expression denoting fear or apprehension

**Lest** existed 400 years before **unless** became part of the language.  See the etymologies of both at dictionary.com.

Answer (score -1):

I think "or" is used when "lest" is meant but sounds too threatening. The meaning is changed though, since "or" separates alternatives, and "lest" separates an action from an undesirable consequence.

Comment: I can't say that I consider 'lest' as threatening. I think there's a bigger chance that it's not used because it's seen as ostentatious (as mentioned in a comment on the question) or old fashioned.

Comment: Use "lest" only in fantasy novels or video games set in "Ye Olden Times".